# Copy cells from a range to a range whose address is a text value in another cell

Tags: excel, vba, copy

In one cell A20, I have a text address of another cell, let's say A366.

I want to copy a range of cells, say A21:T21, to the target range A366.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to copy those specific ranges:

```
Range("A21:T21").Copy Range(Range("A20").Value)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion,  Turns out, for whatever reason, that totally messes up the copy.  Possibly because all of the copied data is indirect.  What eventually worked was code along the lines:  Range([indirect("a2")].Value) = Range("b9").  But your assistance is greatly appreciated by this Newbie. Thanks!

Comment: Shauno-- how do i copy value from a small range of cells (A32:W32 kind of thing), from the curent sheet (call it ONE) to another sheet (call it TWO), when the cell address for the target in sheet TWO is a string in a cell in sheet ONE (i have an address in ONE!B37 (with, let's say a value of A1855).  i want to copy the cells from ONE!A32:W32 to that target area in sheet TWO!A1855.  How do i do that simple copy?